# Intellisense for AMD / Requirejs in Visual Code

Tags: requirejs, visual-studio-code, amd

Is it possible to get Intellisense working in Visual Code when using AMD modules?

I have my jsconfig.json file set to:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

This isn't working. I've searched everywhere but can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else comes across this problem, I resolved it by changing the way I defined the modules.

From this:

```
define(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
```

to this

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
```

Visual Code seems to be able to bring the Intellisense in when using the require method rather than passing an array of dependencies.

Comment: Does this make Intellisense work for modules other than jquery?  (I ask because jquery plays strangely with RequireJS http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to fix this by adding comment references for the required modules.

```
/// <reference path="some-module.js" />
```

some-module.js:

```
var module = {
    member : {}
};

define([], function(){return module;});
```

This allows the intellisense to function because of the missing parameter, but certainly won't run:

```
/// <reference path="some-module.js" />
require(['some-module'], function(){//<--no parameter "module"
     module.member;//intellisense works
});
```

This breaks the intellisense due to hiding, but will actually execute:

```
/// <reference path="some-module.js" />
require(['some-module'], function(module){//<--parameter "module"
     module.member;//no intellisense
});
```

I suppose for now I can delete the parameter while I work on the file and then restore it when I'm done. It feels like a terrible solution. If there was away to turn off the default hiding behavior or to specify that the parameter was the same as the referenced type...

Answer (score 0):

[Require Module Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lici.require-js) provides good Intellisense for AMD / Requirejs if configured correctly.

Comment: vscode-requirejs is not maintained actively and has some issues, see https://github.com/anacierdem/vscode-requirejs/issues